# Using a HTML/CSS/jQuery/JavaScript based theme in an asp.net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, microsoft-metro, themes

I'm fluent in using c#, and recently started on asp.net. No I'm wondering how i can intgrate template themes such as [Metronic](http://themeforest.net/item/metronic-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/4021469). The theme on uploading to a hosting service gives [This](http://swathyfarms.com/testing).

Answer (score 0):

If it is a raw ASP.NET site you can use ASP.NET skins; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx.

With the combination of skins and master pages, you should be able to accomplish what you're looking for.

It's kind of funny, because my own co-worker used that exact theme to create an ASP.NET extranet control panel for a client recently.  And he asked me the same exact question... ^ that was my answer and he managed to spin the site out in less than 3 work days.